# Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' . incomplete mapping. Try completing it with requestUrls().<something>.hasRole('USER')

Tags: java, spring, security, servlets, spring-security

I have an issue that I want to mark all my authenticated. In class tthat extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter I override method configure in this way

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(RequestMatcherResolver.getRequestMatchers())
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(resolveExceptionEntryPoint);
    }
```

But i get an expetion:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: An incomplete mapping was found for []. Try completing it with something like requestUrls().<something>.hasRole('USER')
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: An incomplete mapping was found for []. Try completing it with something like requestUrls().<something>.hasRole('USER')
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: An incomplete mapping was found for []. Try completing it with something like requestUrls().<something>.hasRole('USER')
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: First read your own stackTrace; "Try completing it with something like requestUrls().<something>.hasRole('USER')"

Comment: I saw this biut I dont understand how I can realize this in my example. Can you show pls? sorry if the question is stupid, I'm still completely new to security

Comment: What is does the implementation of `RequestMatcherResolver.getRequestMatchers()` look like?